I need two (25 and 30 kHz) pwm output on a nano
How do I create a second output with a different frequency?
void setup() {

const byte DRIVEa = 3;  // Timer 2 "B" output: OC2B
  pinMode (DRIVEa, OUTPUT);  // driver a.

  TCCR2A = _BV (WGM20) | _BV (WGM21) | _BV (COM2B1); // fast PWM, clear OC2B on compare.
  TCCR2B = _BV (WGM22) | _BV (CS21);         // fast PWM, prescaler of 8.

}

void loop() {

  OCR2A =  ((F_CPU / 8) / 30000) - 1;    // 30kHz, zero relative. 
  OCR2B = ((OCR2A + 1) / 2) - 1;      // 50% duty cycle.

} 


Use a different timer?  The frequency of a timer depends on the mode and the TOP value.  What other timers are you not using?

only using one pwm output and can move other things around if required.  I see on "secrets of PWM" that maybe pin 11 can be a second output??  I borrowed the above code from another post and don't understand how it works.

Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. You did read the manual and application notes of the MCU, didn't you? Please [edit] your question to clarify why they don't help you.

@tedthomas: https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/generic/secrets-of-arduino-pwm/ is good.  https://gammon.com.au/timers explains it very well.  pin11 is also controlled by timer2, and it's PWM-ish register OCR2A is used to set the 30KHz frequency, so it won't work.  Would using Pin 10 on Timer1 with appropriate settings for TCCR1A, TCCR1B, OCR1A and OCR1B be feasible?  The TimerHelpers example on https://gammon.com.au/timers might make it easy.

Try to modify your code like this:
void setup() {
  // Timer 2 - First output (DRIVEa)
  const byte DRIVEa = 3;  // Timer 2 "B" output: OC2B (pin 3 on Arduino UNO)
  pinMode (DRIVEa, OUTPUT);  // driver a
  
  TCCR2A = _BV (WGM20) | _BV (WGM21) | _BV (COM2B1); // fast PWM, clear OC2B on compare
  TCCR2B = _BV (WGM22) | _BV (CS21);                 // fast PWM, prescaler of 8

  // Timer 1 - Second output (DRIVEb)
  const byte DRIVEb = 9;  // Timer 1 "A" output: OC1A (pin 9 on Arduino UNO)
  pinMode (DRIVEb, OUTPUT);  // driver b
  
  TCCR1A = _BV(WGM10) | _BV(WGM11) | _BV(COM1A1);  // fast PWM, clear OC1A on compare
  TCCR1B = _BV(WGM12) | _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS11);    // fast PWM, prescaler of 8
}

void loop() {
  // Timer 2 - Set frequency and duty cycle for first output (DRIVEa)
  OCR2A = ((F_CPU / 8) / 30000) - 1;    // 30kHz frequency
  OCR2B = ((OCR2A + 1) / 2) - 1;        // 50% duty cycle

  // Timer 1 - Set frequency and duty cycle for second output (DRIVEb)
  OCR1A = ((F_CPU / 8) / 10000) - 1;    // 10kHz frequency
  OCR1B = ((OCR1A + 1) / 4) - 1;        // 25% duty cycle (for example)
}

Timer 2 is used for generating the first PWM signal (30kHz) on Pin 3.
Timer 1 is used to generate the second PWM signal (10kHz) on Pin 9.
The prescaler for both timers is set to 8 (CS21 and CS11), but the frequency is determined by the values you set for OCR2A and OCR1A.
You can modify the duty cycle for Timer 1 by adjusting OCR1B.

Timer 2 working like a champ but nothing from Timer 1.

I tried this and get nothing from Timer 1.  I note the Timer 1 uses 0C1"A" where Timer 2 uses B.  and the addition of WGM13

Timer 1 output locked high.  Think it has anything to do with 8 vs 16-bit ?

Used the code on Timers 0 and 2 and it works perfectly.  I need other timer 0 functions so need to get 1 working...

Finally found a solution.  Never could get Timer 1 to act like Timer 2 but this tool
https://dbuezas.github.io/arduino-web-timers/#mcu=ATMEGA328P&timer=1&CompareOutputModeA=toggle&OCR1A=48059&timerMode=FPWM
allowed me to experiment
void setup() {

const byte DRIVEb = 9;  // Timer 1 "A" output: OC1A
pinMode (DRIVEb, OUTPUT);  // driver b

TCCR1A = _BV (COM1A0) | _BV (WGM11) | _BV (WGM10); // fast PWM, toggle
TCCR1B = _BV (WGM13)  | _BV (WGM12) | _BV (CS11);   // fast PWM, prescaler of 8
 

const byte DRIVEa = 3;  // Timer 2 "B" output: OC2B
pinMode (DRIVEa, OUTPUT);  // driver a

TCCR2A = _BV (WGM20) | _BV (WGM21) | _BV (COM2B1); // fast PWM, clear OCR2A on compare
TCCR2B = _BV (WGM22) | _BV (CS21);                 // fast PWM, prescaler of 8

}

void loop() {

OCR2A =  ((F_CPU / 8) / 30000) - 1;    // 30kHz, zero relative  
OCR2B = ((OCR2A + 1) / 2) - 1;         // 50% duty cycle

OCR1A = ((F_CPU / 8 ) / 80000) - 1;    // 40kHz, F/2 toggle mode

} 

